# Longer waits.until getting timed out in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So here's my query. What ive been doing is i have a set of 2.7k+ records that i am performing some operations on via a for loop with waits using selenium in python.

```
for elem in list

WebDriverWait.until(20000,    
 EC.prescence_of_element
_located
 (elem).click()....
```

... several other operations

The waits work until few records upto some 700 records but after that it times out. Idk y such behaviour is happening even i tried with `poll_frequency=10` etc but the outcome remains the same either it misses the click and times out or simply times out. I know that more the waits the lesser the life of driver but i have to perform for all 2.7k+ records. Any suggestions what could be the best wait as i have tried keeping on increase of driverwait value but it stills times out and sometimes even misses the click operation and remain paused for longer time

Comment: Get the size of the element. Loop through 700(any number) at a time, opening and closing the driver.

Comment: Could you please write it in a code

Comment: @arundeepchohan www.repl.it

Comment: What website is he testing it on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because of default timeout for each test case in the suite. try increasing the timeout for each test in pytest configuration file(if your using pytest). Add below code

```
[pytest]
timeout = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do 700 list items at a time now if you wanted to load more elements from the page just tell me.

```
size=len(lst) 
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('url')
for position, item in enumerate(lst):
    try: 
        print(item)
        if(position%700==0 and position!=0):
            driver.close()
            driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.get('url')
    except:
        break
```